# How to connect to an unix domain socket with boost::asio?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I want to create and connect to an `unix domain socket` of type `SOCK_SEQPACKET`  by specifying the path name of the socket endpoint, but this fails to compile in `boost::asio` v1.60:

```
using namespace boost::asio::generic;
seq_packet_protocol proto{AF_UNIX, IPPROTO_SCTP}; // SOCK_SEQPACKET
seq_packet_protocol::socket sock(io_service, proto);
boost::asio::local::basic_endpoint<seq_packet_protocol> ep("/tmp/socket");
sock.connect(ep); // does not compile
```

do you know how to properly create an unix domain socket?

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to keep it simple:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    using boost::asio::local::stream_protocol;

    stream_protocol::socket s(io_service);
    s.connect("/tmp/socket");
}
```

No doubt you can go more lowlevel, but I'm not sure when you'd need that.

**UPDATE 2** In Boost [1.82.0](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_82_0.html), Asio 1.27.0 added `local::seq_packet_protocol`

<strike>**UPDATE** Mimicking the pre-defined `stream_protocol`, here's how to define `seqpacket_protocol`:</strike>

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d7c825aecd7d85c)</kbd>**

```
namespace SeqPacket {
    using namespace boost::asio::local;

    struct seqpacket_protocol
    {
        int type()     const { return IPPROTO_SCTP; }
        int protocol() const { return 0;            }
        int family()   const { return AF_UNIX;      }

        typedef basic_endpoint<seqpacket_protocol> endpoint;
        typedef boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<seqpacket_protocol> socket;
        typedef boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<seqpacket_protocol> acceptor;

#if !defined(BOOST_ASIO_NO_IOSTREAM)
        /// The UNIX domain iostream type.
        typedef boost::asio::basic_socket_iostream<seqpacket_protocol> iostream;
#endif // !defined(BOOST_ASIO_NO_IOSTREAM)
    };
}
```

Just use it in the same pattern:

```
int main() {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    using SeqPacket::seqpacket_protocol;

    seqpacket_protocol::socket s(io_service);
    s.connect("socket");
}
```

Comment: I'll read up a bit to see if I can understand what the SEQPACKET does. I may update if I get it :)

Comment: Updated with a sample that uses `IPPROTO_SCTP` as prescribed.

Comment: many thanks, but I wonder why the authors did not add seqpacket to the ::local protocol set

Comment: There's always gonna be arbitrary choices and skipped features. What matters is that the things are supported in principle.

Comment: should not protocol() be IPPROTO_SCTP and type() 0 (or SOCK_SEQPACKET) ? Secondly, I wrote a server and a client following the asio examples (under unix domain socket) by replacing stream_protocol with seqpacket_protocol and using various combinations of protocol() and type() until the forementioned one. The server runs fine, but the client fails to connect() throwing: "Exception: connect: Invalid argument". Do you have any idea?

Comment: It seems IPPROTO_SCTP is not supported with unix domain sockets, am I right? so I used used (family=AF_UNIX, protocol=0, type=SOCK_SEQPACKET). The server runs fine -apparently- as I said, but the client thorws the exception mentioned above on connect()

Comment: Sadly my disclaimer still holds: "No doubt you can go more lowlevel, but I'm not sure when you'd need that". I have no idea what you're trying to do and whether it makes sense. I was just helping you with the technicals of the code, as you asked.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped a lot! BTW @Martin is right, type should be SOCK_SEQPACKET.

Comment: @Martin they [did in 1.82.0](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_82_0.html), just noticed. You can probably spelunk who contributed it, so as to answer [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37080643/how-to-connect-to-an-unix-domain-socket-with-boostasio/37081979#comment61719806_37081979) more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to sehe's answer, the socket definition is wrong, it should be:

```
typedef boost::asio::basic_seq_packet_socket<seqpacket_protocol> socket;
```

putting it together:

```
namespace SeqPacket {
    struct seqpacket_protocol
    {
        int type()     const { return SOCK_SEQPACKET; }
        int protocol() const { return 0;            }
        int family()   const { return AF_UNIX;      }

        typedef boost::asio::local::basic_endpoint<seqpacket_protocol> endpoint;
        typedef boost::asio::basic_seq_packet_socket<seqpacket_protocol> socket;
        typedef boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<seqpacket_protocol> acceptor;

#if !defined(BOOST_ASIO_NO_IOSTREAM)
        /// The UNIX domain iostream type.
        typedef boost::asio::basic_socket_iostream<seqpacket_protocol> iostream;
#endif // !defined(BOOST_ASIO_NO_IOSTREAM)
    };
}
```

Comment: Fyi, [1.82.0](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_82_0.html), added `local::seq_packet_protocol`